(JavaFX + JTransforms) Image convolution from scratch
Since JavaFX lacks an java.awt.image.ConvolveOp equivalent I started writing a made from scratch Image convolution method. My first approach was based on direct convolution in the spatial domain but it was so slow so I learned about Discrete Fourier Transform. Theory says that multiplying functions in the frequency domain is equivalent to convolving with the Fourier transform in the space domain. How ever I haven’t figure out yet how to perform a proper element wise multiplication between the input image DFT and the kernel DFT. Result image is barely recognizable and full of square artifacts.
My code goes as follows:
public static Image POC1(Image img){

        int w = (int) img.getWidth(); int h = (int) img.getHeight();
        WritableImage res = new WritableImage(w,h);
        double[] input = new double[w * h * 2];
        double[] output = new double[w * h * 2];

        IntStream.range(0, w).forEach(i -> {
            IntStream.range(0, h).forEach(j -> {
                input[i * h * 2 + 2* j] = (img.getPixelReader().getArgb(i, j) & 0xFF) * Math.pow(-1, i + j);
            });
        });

        DoubleFFT_2D inputFFT = new DoubleFFT_2D(w, h);
        inputFFT.complexForward(input);

        double[][] kernel = new double[][]{{1,4,1},{4,-20,4},{1,4,1}};
        double[] kernelInput = new double[kernel.length * 2 * kernel.length];

        IntStream.range(0, kernel.length).forEach(i -> {

            IntStream.range(0, kernel.length).forEach(j -> {

                kernelInput[i * 3 * 2 + 2* j] = kernel[i][j]/9d;
           
            });
           
        });

        DoubleFFT_2D kernelFFT = new DoubleFFT_2D(kernel.length,kernel.length);
        kernelFFT.complexForward(kernelInput);


        //Aquí va F(u,v) * H(u,v)

        IntStream.range(0, (input.length/2)-1).forEach(i -> {

            double realImg = input[2*i]; double realKernel = kernelInput[(2*i) % kernelInput.length];
            double imImg = input[2*i+1]; double imKernel = kernelInput[(2*i+1) % kernelInput.length];

            output[2*i] = realImg * realKernel - imImg * imKernel;
            output[2*i+1] = imImg * realKernel + realImg * imKernel;
           
        });

        inputFFT.complexInverse(output, true);

        IntStream.range(0, w).forEach(i -> {
            IntStream.range(0, h).forEach(j -> {

                int brightness = (int) (output[i * h * 2 + 2* j] * Math.pow(-1, i + j));

                brightness = brightness < 0 ? 0 : (brightness > 255 ? 255 : brightness);

                res.getPixelWriter().setArgb(i, j, (255 << 24) | (brightness << 16) | (brightness << 8) | brightness);
                
            });
        });

        return res;
        
    }

Desired image (Using Java2D ConvolveOp) /// Obtained image (My Method)
Comparison

JavaFX has a class for converting between JavaFX images and AWT images, allowing you to use ConvolveOp.

I'm aware of SwingFXUtils existence but it mess up with platform native GluonFX builds.

If SwingFXUtils is corrupting images, that seems like an important JavaFX bug.  Do you recall which version of JavaFX did that?

Sorry but it does not corrupt images. However I'm cannot use anything AWT related if targeting a GraalVM native-image

refactor that. form functions from your big block of code. debug each function, write tests. [mre]

I've debugged each step individually, the problem is on F(u,v) * H(u,v).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
